# DIsplaying Labels in parallel to RadioButtonList in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am creating a quiz application where upon clicking a button, I have to display the explanation for each option in RadioButtonList. What is the best control to display the explanations? I tried binding a Bulletlist to the explanations field but the linespacing in between the bullets does not match with the linespacing in the radio button list and it looks cumbersome. I use List<> so cant create an adhoc field in DataTable and bind the same to RadiobuttonList's DataTextField.

Plz give me a solution or logic for this..

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Question 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Question 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Question 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="display: none; padding-left: 25px" id="ExplanationContent">
                <label>Explanation 1</label><br />
                <label>Explanation 2</label><br />
                <label>Explanation 3</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="showExplanation()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showExplanation() {
        document.getElementById('ExplanationContent').style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

The explanations are wrapped inside a `<label>` tag to make sure they have the same styling as the text of the radiobuttons.

Comment: Thank you... But in my case, the radiobuttonlist options are populated from the database. So Ideally label too should be populated from database via codebehind.

Comment: That should not be a problem. Put a Literal inside those `<label>` tags and in code behind loop through all the ListItems in the RadioButtonList and fill the corresponding Literals.